# Make Github project folders reflect renamed (lowercase) local folders

Tags: git, github

When I created my Github project, all of my local package names had a capital first letter. I've recently refactored all of my local package names to be all lowercase, and I want my Github project structure to reflect this refactoring, but the problem is that every time I push a new commit the remote Github package names don't change. The case insensitivity is frustrating.

How do I go about changing the Github package names to reflect my lowercase locals?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to not ignore the case:

```
git config --global core.ignorecase false
```

Then double-check git has changed the case of your folder

```
git mv -f Afodler afolder
```

Finally, add, commit and push: GitHub should display the right case.

> fatal: renaming 'foo/my_folder' failed: Permission denied

See "[git mv “permission denied”](https://academe.co.uk/2011/12/git-mv-permission-denied/)": a process is locking your folder. Try and close as much program as you can which could use said folder before trying the rename again.

Comment: I tried git mv -f Afolder afolder and received the following error... 'fatal: renaming '../.../...' failed: Permission denied'

Comment: @credo56 did you see `'../.../...` in the output?

Comment: @credo56 I have edited the answer to address the permission denied issue.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. No, '../.../...' just represents my file location.

Comment: @credo56 OK, then my answer stands. If you are on Windows, you can use the Process Explorer CTRL+F search feature to seek for the process preempting your file. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)